# Как обновить значения полей для экземпляра модели?

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django. Нигде не могу найти решения проблемы, с которой столкнулся, хотя задача чрезмерно стандартная. 
Допустим, у меня есть модель в файле models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = 'Шарик'
```

В бд есть 1 сохраненный экземпляр этой модели.
В файле views.py есть функция:

```
from .models import Dog

def my_update(request):
    i = Dog.objects.get(id=1)
    i.name = 'Бобик'
    i.save()
```

При вызове этой функции я хочу изменить значение поля name для определенного экземпляра. Но никакого сохранения в бд не происходит, имя остается прежним. 
Какой самый быстрый способ внести изменения в бд в моем случае?

Мог бы кто-нибудь написать пример кода? Спасибо

Comment: Очевидно, добавить поле в модель и накатить миграцию в эту БД в соответствии с документацией Django. Вы сейчас не создали ни одного поля модели, и модель у вас пустая и в БД ничего хранить не будет

Comment: Зачем миграция? Мне не нужно менять поле для всех моделей. Мне необходимо изменить значение поля в экземпляре, который уже есть в бд. Сейчас этот экземпляр в поле name имеет значение Шарик, я хочу, чтобы значение изменилось на Бобик и перезаписалось для этого экземпляра в бд

Comment: Этот код должен работать. Метод `save` не переопределяли? Дебажьте объект `i`. покажите его содержание перед сохранением и после сохранения.

Comment: @RobCapa в коде вашей модели нет абсолютно никакой связи с полем в бд. Миграция может и не нужна, но выкинуть строку name и заменить её на хотя бы CharField - абсолютно точно нужно, чтобы появилась связь с бд.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dog(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_legnth=200)

def update(request):

    try:
        dog = Dog.objects.get(pk=1)
        dog.name = 'Не шарик'
        dog.save()
    except Dog.DoesNotExists:
        raise Http404

    return HttpResponse(........)
```

Почитайте туториал по django, там поясняется как она работает :)